# How to rid of extra white space?

Tags: php, spacing, nl2br

I have a textbox that i use nl2br to insert into db.  The problem is that 
 is adding too much space.  Is there a way to assign this an id while being processed or some other way to reduce the space between sentences?

Comment: What do you mean,  "adding too much space"? Can you show an example?

Comment: you usually want to apply nl2br() on the output, leave the raw line breaks in the db, and save some space.

Comment: extra space characters can be removed with trim() or a regular expression depending where they are.

Comment: use regex for that preg_replace("/(\n)+/","",$str);

Comment: @dagon i tried it that was as well.  didn't make a difference.

Comment: What database are you using? Most will have a trim function.

Comment: @AAA, i made 3 suggestions, what did you try? can you provide an example of the string your trying to modify, and the result you want.

Comment: @dagon i am not sure how to use trim() but for now i am using line-height.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you want is some cleanups of those lines.
This is what I use on my php apps.

```
<?php
function trimlines($html){
    $ret = str_replace("\r\n","\n",$html);
    $ret = explode("\n",$ret);
    $ret = array_map('trim',$ret);
    $ret = join("\r\n",$ret);
    return $ret;
}
?>
```

Regular expressions can also be used, but for quick cleanups, this works well for me.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey! it didn't work.  i doesn't give me an output, i replaced $html with the variable i needed to get this done for.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest wrapping the variable in sql with TRIM('sentences here')